# Unique columns in Sugar ORM

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sugarorm

Is it possible to create columns that are unique with Sugar ORM? Or is it possible to insert or replace specified row, let's say by username, however this username may be not in db cause he may not has been created.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not supported yet in the official release 1.3. But you could use the latest source https://github.com/satyan/sugar for this functionality.

Unique constraint can be specified using @Unique annotation. The default behaviour currently is to replace on conflict. So, if the unique constraint is violated, it'd replace the existing row.

Comment: Please add this in gradle

Comment: Hello @Satya, is the SugarOrm 1.3.1 support "@Unique", I use compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.3.1' on gradle

Comment: @Satya very interesting ! Is it possible to set other behaviours on violated constraint ?

Comment: what if we want to make a pair of column unique like username and user phoneno together unique i.e. they can repeat the same values but not in the pair.

Comment: How to remove `Unique` constraint from a column. I want to save duplicated data in the column. Getting the following error:  `code 1555 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY`.

Answer (score 2):

As Satya said, there is no official annotation into the latest stable release but you can use the `@Unique` annotation with the latest pre-release version. I don't know what that annotation does but I tried it and found I should check the database for same result and if the returned list is empty, so that data is unique. Here an example is:

```
if (Contacts.find(Contacts.class, "phone_number = ?", phoneNumber.getText().toString())
                .isEmpty()) {
            new Contacts(fullName.getText().toString(),
                    phoneNumber.getText().toString(),
                    picture.toString()).save();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Already exists!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use @Unique annotation on your db class.

com.github.satyan:sugar:1.4